# How to set up knowrob?

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I already downloaded knowrob stack and i put it at ~/opt/ros/
but when i try to write to set it up
"rosdep satisfy knowrob" command at the terminal
i got that error
"rosdep: error: Unsupported command satisfy."
and i got that command from
[Tutorial :Knowrob basic](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:_KnowRob_basics)

at the setting up section .

what shall i do to set that stack up ??.....
Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45609/how-to-set-up-knowrob-?/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-11**:
i typed that command
"sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob"
and i got that error
"Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-knowrob"

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-11**:
i am using ubuntu not debian sir...what shall i do now ???

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-10-11**:
Have you set up your Ubuntu repositories as described here? Then the package should be found.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-12**:
Thank you very much sir...now i have knowrob installed ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just install it from debian packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob
```

This command installs the complete stack and all its dependencies. A call to rosdep is then not required anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1